# probability lottery ticket

Tags: probability

A lottery has tickets numbered 000 to 999 which are sold for 1 dollar each. One  ticket is  selected  at random and a prize of  200 dollars is given to any person whose ticket number is a permutation of the selected ticket number. All 1000 tickets are sold. What is the expected profit or loss to the organization running the lottery?

Comment: Is the ticket a 3-digit ticket with each digit from $0$ to $9$?  Then, the tricky part is that some tickets are more likely to win, i.e. 111 only happens 1 way, but 323 could win with a drawing of any of 233, 323, 332?

Comment: Yes u r right.. thats sth i didnt even consider

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**:

Note, there are three cases to consider.

- All three digits are different
- Two of the three digits are the same
- All of the digits are the same

How many winning tickets are there if the ticket drawn is something like 123 with all numbers different?  What does this say about the total profit?

How many winning tickets are there if the ticket drawn is something like 112 with two numbers the same?  What does this say about the total profit?

How many winning tickets are there if it is something like 111 with all three numbers the same?  What does this say about the total profit?

What are the chances of being in each of the different states?

If you define a random variable, $X$, to be the total profit, how do you use the previously determined information to find $E[X]$?